MS EXCEL: Formula to calculate days where I was on a trip between 2 input dates from a table with start and end dates of all trips taken
I have a table (below) with start and end dates of trips I have taken. I want to create a formula in which I input a period start and end date, and it gives me the number of days I was on a trip during this period.
Trips table:



Start   trip
End trip




27-May-20
30-Aug-20


19-Dec-20
18-Feb-21


17-Mar-21
23-Sep-21


18-Nov-21
21-Nov-21


20-Dec-21
3-Jan-22


24-Feb-22
28-Feb-22


23-Apr-22
8-May-22


10-Jun-22
12-Jun-22


8-Jul-22
15-Jul-22


24-Jul-22
24-Jul-22


30-Jul-22
1-Aug-22


5-Aug-22
7-Aug-22


21-Oct-22
26-Oct-22


24-Nov-22
8-Jan-23


23-Jan-23
15-Feb-23


3-Jun-23
4-Jun-23


24-Jun-23
3-Jul-23


7-Jul-23
19-Jul-23


1-Aug-23
19-Aug-23


8-Dec-23
15-Jan-24


8-Mar-24
17-Mar-24


5-Apr-24
11-May-24


9-Jun-24
22-Jun-24



Table with start and end dates of trips
So basically, if I put period start as 29th May 2020 and period end as 19th May 2021, output should be 157 trip days (93 days from 29 May 2020 until 30 Aug 2020, 61 days from 19 Dec 2020 until 18 Feb 2021 and 3 days from 17 May 2021 until 19 May 2021).
I tried using sumifs with a trip start dates greater than period start and trip end dates < period end. But answer is not precise in cases where the period start or period end falls in the middle of a trip.

datedif() or date1 - date2 or networkdays.intl()

Thanks Mike, how does this take into account the trips table?

Could you add your data as a table that can be copy/pasted please.  https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

This may  be a bit hard to explain.
I copied the data into cell A1:B24
I put the start date 5/29/2020 into cell E2
I put the end date 5/19/2021 into cell F2
I put the following formula into cell C2 and copied down to cell C24: =MAX(0,DAYS(MIN(B2,F$2),MAX(A2,E$2)))
I put the following formula into cell G2: =SUM(C2:C24)



Start trip
End trip
Days






27-May-20
30-Aug-20
93




19-Dec-20
18-Feb-21
61




17-Mar-21
23-Sep-21
63




18-Nov-21
21-Nov-21
0




20-Dec-21
3-Jan-22
0




24-Feb-22
28-Feb-22
0




23-Apr-22
8-May-22
0




10-Jun-22
12-Jun-22
0




8-Jul-22
15-Jul-22
0




24-Jul-22
24-Jul-22
0




30-Jul-22
1-Aug-22
0




5-Aug-22
7-Aug-22
0




21-Oct-22
26-Oct-22
0




24-Nov-22
8-Jan-23
0




23-Jan-23
15-Feb-23
0




3-Jun-23
4-Jun-23
0




24-Jun-23
3-Jul-23
0




7-Jul-23
19-Jul-23
0




1-Aug-23
19-Aug-23
0




8-Dec-23
15-Jan-24
0




8-Mar-24
17-Mar-24
0




5-Apr-24
11-May-24
0




9-Jun-24
22-Jun-24
0








Start
End
Days




5/29/2020
5/19/2021
217




I don't know if there is a formula that can do that, but with simple math you can do what you want.
Check this :
STARTPERIOD = 29/05/2020
ENDPERIOD = 19/05/2021
The sum of the Day column return 157.

You can if you wish combine each columns formula to obtain a single formula for each row like
=MAX((B2-A2)-(MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A2,0)+MAX((B2-ENDPERIOD),0)),0)



Entry
Exit

Total Day Between
Day Before
Day After
Trip Day




27/05/2020
30/08/2020

=(B2-A2)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A2,0)
=MAX((B2-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D2-(E2+F2),0)


19/12/2020
18/02/2021

=(B3-A3)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A3,0)
=MAX((B3-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D3-(E3+F3),0)


17/05/2021
23/09/2021

=(B4-A4)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A4,0)
=MAX((B4-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D4-(E4+F4),0)


18/11/2021
21/11/2021

=(B5-A5)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A5,0)
=MAX((B5-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D5-(E5+F5),0)


20/12/2021
03/01/2022

=(B6-A6)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A6,0)
=MAX((B6-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D6-(E6+F6),0)


24/02/2022
28/02/2022

=(B7-A7)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A7,0)
=MAX((B7-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D7-(E7+F7),0)


23/04/2022
08/05/2022

=(B8-A8)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A8,0)
=MAX((B8-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D8-(E8+F8),0)


10/06/2022
12/06/2022

=(B9-A9)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A9,0)
=MAX((B9-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D9-(E9+F9),0)


08/07/2022
15/07/2022

=(B10-A10)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A10,0)
=MAX((B10-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D10-(E10+F10),0)


24/07/2022
24/07/2022

=(B11-A11)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A11,0)
=MAX((B11-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D11-(E11+F11),0)


30/07/2022
01/08/2022

=(B12-A12)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A12,0)
=MAX((B12-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D12-(E12+F12),0)


05/08/2022
07/08/2022

=(B13-A13)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A13,0)
=MAX((B13-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D13-(E13+F13),0)


21/10/2022
26/10/2022

=(B14-A14)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A14,0)
=MAX((B14-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D14-(E14+F14),0)


24/11/2022
08/01/2023

=(B15-A15)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A15,0)
=MAX((B15-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D15-(E15+F15),0)


23/01/2023
15/02/2023

=(B16-A16)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A16,0)
=MAX((B16-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D16-(E16+F16),0)


03/06/2023
04/06/2023

=(B17-A17)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A17,0)
=MAX((B17-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D17-(E17+F17),0)


24/06/2023
03/07/2023

=(B18-A18)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A18,0)
=MAX((B18-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D18-(E18+F18),0)


07/07/2023
19/07/2023

=(B19-A19)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A19,0)
=MAX((B19-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D19-(E19+F19),0)


01/08/2023
19/08/2023

=(B20-A20)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A20,0)
=MAX((B20-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D20-(E20+F20),0)


08/12/2023
15/01/2024

=(B21-A21)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A21,0)
=MAX((B21-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D21-(E21+F21),0)


08/03/2024
17/03/2024

=(B22-A22)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A22,0)
=MAX((B22-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D22-(E22+F22),0)


05/04/2024
11/05/2024

=(B23-A23)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A23,0)
=MAX((B23-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D23-(E23+F23),0)


09/06/2024
22/06/2024

=(B24-A24)
=MAX((STARTPERIOD-1)-A24,0)
=MAX((B24-ENDPERIOD),0)
=MAX(D24-(E24+F24),0)




If you have 365 you can do this with a single formula:
=SUM(
    BYROW(
        Trips,
        LAMBDA(a,
            MAX(
                0,
                MIN(CHOOSECOLS(a, 2), Period_End) -
                    MAX(CHOOSECOLS(a, 1), Period_Start)
            )
        )
    )
)

Trips is the two column data source which I have made into a table for convenience as the cell references will auto-adjust as you add data.


This makes use of the filter, let, choosecols functions, so you'd need to modify this is a bit if your version of excel doesn't support.
Basically, you first filter the range of values so that only the values where the start date of your trip is greater than  or equal to your analysis start date. Then you filter out the values where your trip end date is less then or equal to your analysis end date. If both are true, when the results are multiplied together and set to a 1 or 0 with the -- operation, you should get only a 1 in the resulting array.
After that, I put the function in a LET function, setting column 1 to be equal to the start variable, and column 2 equal to the stop variable. After that, you subtract the start range from the stop range, summing the result, giving you a total amount of days.
=LET(start, 
           CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(My_Trips, (-- 
           (CHOOSECOLS(My_Trips, 1)>=$D$2)*(-- 
           (CHOOSECOLS(My_Trips, 2) 
           <=$E$2)=1))),1),
     stop, 
           CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(My_Trips, (-- 
           CHOOSECOLS(My_Trips, 1)>=$D$2)*(-- 
           (CHOOSECOLS(My_Trips, 2) 
           <=$E$2)=1))),2), 
    SUM(stop-start))


